# How would I implement jquery into my existing dropdown listings

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, user-interface

I want to implement this jquery into my existing dropdown list. The one I want to intergrate is https://codepen.io/Carike/pen/QyEQeN

Ive placed this code into my template and its working fine. But I just would want to integrate with my own dropdown. How would I do that?

Here's my Code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
 <div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="governorate" name="governorate">

   <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">{% trans 'Governorate' %}</option>

   <option value="{{ governorate.name_ar }}"  data-governorate="{{governorate.id}}">{{ governorate.name_ar }}</option>

  </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here's the actual code I want to integrate its functionalities with my  tags.

```
<div>
 <ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">Kinda Tall Menu</a>
   <ul class="sub_menu">

    <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>

   </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, my code is just retreiving the data and listing them on the basis of the feilds mentioned there such as governorate.name_ar. It is listing all the governorate names in a listing form or dropdown. I just want to have the same functionality into my listings.

Thank you in advance :D